# Локальный URL в Ajax MVC

Tags: url, ajax, mvc

Здравствуйте!
Работаю с ASP.NET MVC 4.
Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при выполнении действия страница не перезагружалась.
Делаю это с помощью ajax скрипта, но скрипт не читает мой url (Отладку выполняю через студию локально). Когда писал с отладкой на сервере, там все работало, но там в юрл указывался полный адрес, а что указывать если работаешь локально?

```
function AddNewDoc() {
            alert('In!');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Index/AddNewDoc_',
                data: { 'Title': Title
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Done!');
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    alert('Ошибка запроса к серверу');
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
```

1-ый алерт срабатывает, а второй уже нет. И метод AddNewDoc_ не срабатывает.

Пробовал сделать так - `url: 'http://localhost/Index/AddNewDoc_'` - не удалось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller")'
```